# How to send videos through the network with the Photon PUN?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, photon

> Hi everyone !

I'm quite new to Photon and I'm currently making a phone app that is basically a game in which you have to send videos on specific themes to the players who are in the same room as you. I built the whole room connection system with the Photon PUN , and now I'm trying to send videos through the network with an RPC (by the way, if there is a better solution for this, please tell me). My problem is about serializing the Unity VideoClip, which is not serializable, and then send as a byte[] to the other clients in the room with the RPC. How should I do this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Reflection;
public static class DataConverter
{

    public static byte[] SerializeObject(T objectToSerialize)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(mStream, objectToSerialize);
        mStream.Position = 0;
        return mStream.ToArray();
    }
    public static T DeserializeObject(byte[] dataStream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(dataStream);
        mStream.Position = 0;
        bf.Binder = new VersionFixer();
        T o = (T)bf.Deserialize(mStream);
        return o;
    }
sealed class VersionFixer : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;

        // For each assemblyName/typeName that you want to deserialize to
        // a different type, set typeToDeserialize to the desired type.
        String assemVer1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        if (assemblyName != assemVer1)
        {
            // To use a type from a different assembly version, 
            // change the version number.
            // To do this, uncomment the following line of code.
            assemblyName = assemVer1;
            // To use a different type from the same assembly, 
            // change the type name.
        }
        // The following line of code returns the type.
        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, 
        assemblyName));
        return typeToDeserialize;

    }
 }
```

I found this bit of code for serializing on the Internet, but I don't understand the VersionFixer part, and anyway, again, the problem is that VideoClip is not Serializable.

Comment: Well, the `videoclip` is a component in Unity.  What I would try to do would be to serialize/send the raw video data over the network.  I'm not sure how you're getting your video footage into Unity, but if you could capture that you might be able to convert it to a byte array.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But how do you get the raw video data ? I don't see any method to do this in the Unity documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting your video footage now, but if you're recording it through a webcam then you might want to take a look at this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html.  It can save videos from your webcam to a file.  Then, you coulsd send the file as a byte array over the network, download it to the other players' devices, and then point their `VideoClip` to that file.

Comment: Oh so the VideoCapture tool also work for webcams? I thought it was to record inside the unity app.

Comment: It's under the `Webcamera` namespace so I'd assume so.